# ORA-00904: : invalid identifier in Oracle Life database

Tags: sql, oracle

Even i run this as script, i got error. first i didnt use 'wrent_id' and still got error.

```
CREATE TABLE want_renting ( 
    'wrent_id' int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    'property_id' int, 
    'client_id' int, 
    'agent_id' int, 
    'wrent_date' date, 
    'expired_date' date, 
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_property'  FOREIGN KEY ('property_id') REFERENCES 'property'('property_id'), 
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_client'  FOREIGN KEY ('client_id')  REFERENCES 'clients'('client_id'), 
    CONSTRAINT 'fk_agent'  FOREIGN KEY ('agent_id')  REFERENCES 'agents'('agent_id'),  
);
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

Comment: You have a superfluous comma after the last constraint. Voting to Close as typo.

Comment: You are using single quotes where you should be using double quotes and have a superfluous comma.  These are typos.

Comment: I would partially disagree with @GordonLinoff.  He is technichlly correct on the single-quote vs. double-quote. However, I disagree with "_should_ use double-quotes".  If you create object names (table names, column names, etc) with double-quotes, you are creating case-sensitive names.  All future references to those names will have to be in double-quotes and the case match exactly.  In oracle, it is better to create case-INsensitive names by _not_ using double-quotes at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove quotes from your query. Quotes is used to define a string and not during table creation.

```
CREATE TABLE want_renting ( 
wrent_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
property_id int, 
client_id int, 
agent_id int, 
wrent_date date, 
expired_date date, 
CONSTRAINT fk_property  FOREIGN KEY (property_id) REFERENCES 
property(property_id), 
CONSTRAINT fk_client  FOREIGN KEY (client_id)  REFERENCES clients(client_id), 
CONSTRAINT fk_agent  FOREIGN KEY (agent_id)  REFERENCES agents(agent_id)  
);
```

And make sure you have all other tables referencing the foreign keys.

Comment: i remove quotes and still Invalid identifier

Comment: then check if you have all these tables property, clients and agents

Comment: And as Salmon said, remove the comma in end of the last constraint. Use the query, have edited